# Handling return of enum with generic and non generic type in rust

Tags: rust, redis

I am trying to create striped down redis clone in Rust. I got stuck trying to implement redis protocol.
I want to have a struct that would encapsulate incoming packet and parse it appropriately to its data type and command.

My data types are simple Strings or Ints, but one thing is kinda different for Array data type i would like to use `Vec<T>`  and this is where my problems begin.

So i created struct that represents my incoming packet.
What to want to archive with this struct to be able to just do:
`let parsed_value = ProtocolPacket::new(data: &[u8])`

```
struct ProtocolPacket <T> {  //  <-- this <T> is only because of ProtocolPacketData<T>
    command: ProtocolPacketCommand,
    data: ProtocolPacketData<T>,
}
impl <T>ProtocolPacket <T> {
    fn new(packet: &[u8]) -> ProtocolPacket<T> {
        let packet = packet.into_iter();
        let command = ProtocolPacketCommand::new(packet.next().unwrap()); // <-- This is working
    // Delete \r \n
    packet.next_back().unwrap();
    packet.next_back().unwrap();

    let data = packet.as_slice();
    let data = ProtocolPacketData::new(data);


    ProtocolPacket{
        command: command,
        data: data,
    }
}
enum ProtocolPacketData <T> {
    SimpleString(String), 
    Error(String),
    Integer(i64), 
    String(String), 
    Array(Vec<T>),
}

impl <T> ProtocolPacketData <T> {
    pub fn new(rest: &[u8]) -> ProtocolPacketData<T> {
        let rest = rest.into_iter();
        let data_type  = rest.next().unwrap();

        // Strip last 2 bytes -> \r\n
        rest.next_back().unwrap();
        rest.next_back().unwrap();

        match data_type.to_string().chars().next().unwrap() {
            '+' => handle_packet_simplestring(rest.as_slice()), <-- Function call that returns ProtocolPacketData<String>
            '-' =>   unimplemented!()
            ':' =>   unimplemented!()
            '$' =>   unimplemented!()
            '*' =>   unimplemented!()
            '%' =>   unimplemented!()
            _ =>    unimplemented!()
        }
    }
}


fn handle_packet_simplestring<T>(packet_value: &[u8]) -> ProtocolPacketData<String>{
    let data = String::from_utf8_lossy(packet_value);
    ProtocolPacketData::SimpleString(data.to_string())
}
```

This is where my error occours

```
    match data_type.to_string().chars().next().unwrap() {
        '+' => handle_packet_simplestring(rest.as_slice()), <-- Function call that returns ProtocolPacketData<String>
        '-' =>   unimplemented!()
        ':' =>   unimplemented!()
        '$' =>   unimplemented!()
        '*' =>   unimplemented!()
        '%' =>   unimplemented!()
        _ =>    unimplemented!()
    }
```

I get an error

```
mismatched types
expected enum ProtocolPacketData<T>
   found enum ProtocolPacketData<std::string::String>
```

How can i make this work and is this even viable way to do this?
Thanks, Sam

Comment: Well your function signature claims that it returns `ProtocalPacketData<T>` but then you try to return `ProtocolPacketData<String>`.

Did you mean to provide a type-specific implementation, like `impl ProtocolPacketData<String>`?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the very quick reply. I might have don't i? Will i still be able to call on the enum like so: `ProtocolPacketData::new(rest: &[u8])` if i implement `pub fn new(rest: &[u8])`  with return type of which i implement for? I was kinda hoping i could do this less explicitly. I think you've pointed me to the right direction. I'll come back to report my progress. Thank you!

Comment: Or _maybe_ you meant to have it so that ProtocolPacketDate<String> can be _converted_ to ProtocolPacketData<T>? In which case I guess you'd need to add the trait bound `T: From<String>` in the appropriate places and then do the conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are literally lying to the compiler. The `impl<T> ProtocolPacketData<T>` means that the "outside" of `ProtocolPacketData<T>` gets to decide whatever *it* wants `T` to be and that `impl` must apply. For example one should be able to do `let x: ProtocolPacketData::<f64> = ProtocolPacketData::new(&buffer)`; but `handle_packet_simplestring` then puts a `String` where a `f64` has to be. The compiler is trying to tell you that: It expects a `ProtocolPacketData<T>` - with no restriction on `T` - but you returned a *specific* `ProtocolPacketData<String>` (to which the other match-arms coerce because `unimplemented!()` returns `!`, so the compiler concludes it has to be `String` in any and all cases, regardless of `T`).

You probably want to remove the `T`-parameter entirely and extend `ProtocolPacketData` such as

```
enum ProtocolPacketData {
    // ...
    StringArray(Vec<Box<str>>),
    IntArray(Vec<u64>),
    // ...
}
```

and your big `match` returning a specific variant.

Another possibility is to

```
enum ProtocolPacketData {
    // ...
    Array(Vec<ProtocolPacketData>),
}
```

which makes the `Array` variant simpler; yet it allows for heterogeneous arrays (`[Integer, String, Array[String, String]]`) which may not be what you want.

Comment: I think the second example you've shown is something i want to do. I tried to refactor my code to convert any incoming data type to string. I did this because i would simplify the HashMap implementation for the actual in memory storage. But looking back i think i will try to implement it the way i intended from the examples i've shown in this thread. It will be more challenging, but its more fun learning rust by creating something. I'll flag this as an answer to my question, Thank you!